# How to resolve generic type of property value from decorated property in decorator

Tags: typescript, generics, generic-programming, typescript-decorator

I'm playing with some code, which resolve generic type of property value and doesn't allow provide wrong value. But when I change from `TValue` to `(t: TValue) => TValue`, type `TValue` doesn't going resolved more. It's now unknown `{}` type, not `number` more

Example without function. Working good

```js
type ProtoOf<T> = Pick<T, keyof T>;

function decorate<TValue>(value: TValue) {
  return <T extends { [KA in TKey]: TValue }, TKey extends keyof T>(
    proto: ProtoOf<T> & { [P in TKey]: TValue },
    propertyKey: TKey
  ) => {};
}

class Foo {
  // TS error: none
  // Result: EXPECTED
  @decorate(1) bar: number = 1;

  // TS Error:
  // Types of property 'wrongBar' are incompatible
  // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
  // Result: EXPECTED
  @decorate('') wrongBar: number = 1;
}
```

Example with function. Don't working as expected

```js
type ProtoOf<T> = Pick<T, keyof T>;

function decorate<TValue>(getValue: (t: TValue) => TValue) {
  return <T extends { [KA in TKey]: TValue }, TKey extends keyof T>(
    proto: ProtoOf<T> & { [P in TKey]: TValue },
    propertyKey: TKey
  ) => {};
}

class Foo {
  // TS Error: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types '{}' and '1'
  // Result: NOT EXPECTED: because we can assign `number` to `number`
  @decorate(v => v + 1) bar: number = 1;

  // TS error: none
  // Result: NOT EXPECTED: we should have error, we cannot assign `string` to `number`
  @decorate(v => v + '') wrongBar: number = 1;
}
```

I'm expected `TValue` equal `number` in example with function as in example without function

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2607

Comment: @jcalz Thanks. I written before in this issue (24 January), but still don't get answer
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2607#issuecomment-457261614

For example, in my project I make force passing types to decorator https://github.com/artemirq/zero-scriptsjs/blob/master/packages/config.webpack/src/WebpackConfigOptions.ts#L9
I believe that we can get a good solution without force passing type to decorator and this code can be more clean :c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2607), as you are aware from your GitHub comments.  Summarizing here:

Currently, type inference does not work the way you want it to, as the compiler treats the original as equivalent to something like this:

```
const barDeco = decorate(v => v + 1); // error
barDeco(Foo.prototype, "bar");
const wrongBarDeco = decorate(v => v + '');
wrongBarDeco(Foo.prototype, "wrongBar");
```

And the calls to `decorate()` in `barDeco` and `wrongBarDeco` don't have enough type information for the compiler to infer the generic type, and thus it is inferred as `{}`, resulting in much sadness.  The decorator is basically a curried function `f(x)(y)`, and to fix this the compiler would have to infer the type of `f` from the type of `y`, which is a new sort of contextual typing.  Maybe decorators could be special-cased for such inference; it would likely be a massive breaking change to do that with curried functions in general.

For now the only way to deal with this is to manually specify the generic parameter when calling the decorator as in

```
class Foo {
  @decorate<number>(v => v + 1) bar: number = 1; // okay
  @decorate<number>(v => v + '') wrongBar: number = 1; // error
}
```

or to manually annotate your callback as in

```
class Foo {
  @decorate((v: number) => v + 1) bar: number = 1; // okay
  @decorate((v: number) => v + '') wrongBar: number = 1; // error
}
```

These workarounds are not optimal, but they do work, so you have some way to deal with things unless and until [Microsoft/TypeScript#2607](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2607) is addressed.  There are many, many open issues, so I wouldn't expect to see much movement on this one.  The likelihood will increase if  more people go to that issue and give it a  and describe compelling use cases and compelling reasons why the workarounds are insufficient.  Since you have already done this, I think there isn't much left for you to do but move on.  If future readers care about this, they can check out the issue in GitHub and contribute.

Sorry there isn't a better answer for you.  Good luck!