# Can't get typescript method decorator to infer argument types

Tags: typescript, decorator

I'm trying to create a Memoize decorator and I'm mimicking lodash's memoize function but as a decorator. I'm having difficulties in getting TypeScript to infer the arguments for the resolver function.

```
export function Memoize<T extends any[], C>(resolver?: (...args: T) => C) { 
    return function <D>(target: object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: T) => D>) { 
        const original = descriptor.value;

        if (!original) { 
            throw new Error(`Can't be undefined!`);
        }

        descriptor.value = function (...args: T): D {
            const key: C = resolver ? resolver.apply(this, args) : args[0];
            const result: D = original.apply(this, args);

            console.log(key);

            return result;
        };

        return descriptor;
    }
}

class Test {
    @Memoize(t => t)
    public test(test: string): string { 
        return test;
    }
}
```

The callback passed into memoize is inferred as: `<[any], any>`, but I want it to be inferred as: `[string], string`

For example:

```
class Test {
   @Memoize(test => test)
   public test1(value: string): string {
      return value;
   }

   @Memoize(test => test)
   public test2(value: string): Observable<string> {
      return of(value);
   }

   @Memoize(test => test.test)
   public test3(value: { test: string }): Observable<{ test: string }> {
      return of(value);
   }

   @Memoize()
   public get test4(): string {
       return '123';
   }
}
```

The callback passed into the Memoize decorator I want to infer the typings.

So for test 1, test is string in both the argument and return.
For test 2, same thing, string for both argument and return.
Test 3, argument is `{ test: string }` and return is string.
Test 4 is a getter and has not resolver available, so nothing to infer.

setters will just throw if decorator is present on them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve generic type of property value from decorated property in decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55409151/how-to-resolve-generic-type-of-property-value-from-decorated-property-in-decorat)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to provide type safety to method decorator options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56403431/2887218)

Comment: @jcalz, thanks for linking these, I did do a search for these on stack overflow and the typescript github, but my search terms must not have matched these.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to provide type safety to method decorator options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56403431/is-it-possible-to-provide-type-safety-to-method-decorator-options)